# Problem when I try to change a picture regarding the size of the screen

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I was trying to do a page of my curriculum, and I would like to change the photo of the top depends of the size on screen.

I was trying to do with Javascript but doesn't work

I get the following error:

```
Curriculum.html:33 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Curriculum.html:37 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
Curriculum.html:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

foto_curriculum_1200.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

foto_curriculum_1000.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Of course if I try to draw the picture without consider the size of the picture it's work, so the route are OK.

the code of my proyect is this:

```
<script>


var width = screen.width; 
var height = screen.height;

alert('Welcome to my personal Page!');

  </script>

   <body onload=animar() >
       <div class="main_container">
           
               <div>
                   <h1><i>Manuel Lucas Sánchez</i></h1>

                   <script>if(width>=1200 && height>=1600){</script>

                       <img class="foto_cabecera" src="../img/foto_curriculum_1200.png" alt="foto_1200">

                   <script>}else{</script>

                       <img class="foto_cabecera" src="../img/foto_curriculum_1000.png" alt="foto_1000">
                       
                   <script>}</script>
                   
                  
                   
               </div>
               <p><i>Biotecnólogo, apasionado por la tecnología, y futuro desarrolllador de aplicacciones.</i></p>
           
       </div>
```

I read that with the tag  it's posible but doens't work neither.

thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how scripts work in html/javascript.

You are getting this error because the script doesn't complete. Each script tag needs to have a working script within. A simple `{` is not executable code and is thus throwing an error.

I would recommend looking into tools that can help you with this. Try looking into frameworks like Angular, Node, or JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper, working `script`you can not have `<script>}</script>`